# Why multiple nodes are created in Neo4j by CREATE or MERGE query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cypher-3.1

I'm using `Cypher` to create some data in `Neo4j`. It's a pretty straight forward product model, with following elements

1. Product (e.g. a mobile)
2. Features (e.g. quick charge)
3. Related products (e.g. tampered glass)
4. Outlets (e.g. local store, related products are sold through outlets)

I have written some query to insert the data. What it *tries to do* is

- Create a product
- Create a feature set
- Link product with feature [:HAS_FEATURES]
- Create outlets x3
- Create related product 1
- Link product to related product [:HAS_RP], and related product to all outlets [:SOLD_THROUGH]
- Create related product 2
- Link it to product & outlets like above

Below is the actual query

```
//Product
CREATE (p:Product {name: 'Cool Mobile YX Plus',
  key: 'MOB0001',
  version: 'X.1'
}),

//Features
(f:Features {hasQuickCharge: true,
  isAvailable: true,
  hasVolte: false
})

MERGE (p) -[:HAS_FEATURES]-> (f)

//Outlets (:Product level lookup)
CREATE (o1:Outlet {productType: 'New', seller: 'National_Shops', prId: 'MOB0001'})
CREATE (o2:Outlet {productType: 'New', seller: 'Local_Shops', prId: 'MOB0001'})
CREATE (o3:Outlet {productType: 'New', seller: 'Online_Shops', prId: 'MOB0001'})

//Related products
CREATE (rps1:RPS {rpId: 'TGS1108',
  rpName: 'YX Plus Tampered Glass',
  price: 180.99
})
WITH rps1
MATCH (ol1:Outlet {productType: 'New', prId: 'MOB0001'})
MATCH (pr1:Product {key: 'MOB0001'})
MERGE (pr1) -[:HAS_RP {typeName: 'Child'}]-> (rps1)
MERGE (rps1) -[:SOLD_THROUGH]-> (ol1)

CREATE (rps2:RPS {rpId: 'CVR0204',
  rpName: 'YX Plus back cover',
  price: 299.00
})
WITH rps2
MATCH (ol2:Outlet {productType: 'New', prId: 'MOB0001'})
MATCH (pr2:Product {key: 'MOB0001'})
MERGE (pr2) -[:HAS_RP {typeName: 'ChargeFor'}]-> (rps2)
MERGE (rps2) -[:SOLD_THROUGH]-> (ol2)
```

Now the problem is, the **second related product is created 3 times**, where it was expected to be created only once, just like the first related product.

Can anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Also, any help in writing the query in better way would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is located here :

`MATCH (ol1:Outlet {productType: 'New', prId: 'MOB0001'})`

You created before 3 nodes that comply to the criteria of the MATCH :

`CREATE (o1:Outlet {productType: 'New', seller: 'National_Shops', prId: 'MOB0001'})
CREATE (o2:Outlet {productType: 'New', seller: 'Local_Shops', prId: 'MOB0001'})
CREATE (o3:Outlet {productType: 'New', seller: 'Online_Shops', prId: 'MOB0001'})`

So,  `MATCH (ol1:Outlet {productType: 'New', prId: 'MOB0001'})` will return 3 rows, and for each row, it will execute the next part of the query, 3 times this part :

```
MATCH (pr2:Product {key: 'MOB0001'})
MERGE (pr2) -[:HAS_RP {typeName: 'ChargeFor'}]-> (rps2)
MERGE (rps2) -[:SOLD_THROUGH]-> (ol2)
```

Comment: As a supplement, here's a knowledge base article on [resetting cardinality](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/resetting-query-cardinality/) between unrelated parts of a query, as in this case.

Comment: Hi Christophe, thanks for your answer. My confusion is, why this is happening ONLY for the second query (YX Plus back cover), but not for the first one (YX Plus Tampered Glass) ? For example, if I remove the second one, first one works just fine!

Comment: @InverseFalcon ah, now I got it. Thanks for the link. So, it was NOT the MERGE parts that was creating the issue (as explained in the link, that is heavy but works), but the CREATE (YX Plus back cover) was triggered 3 times!

Answer (score 0):

Just writing an extension to what @Christophe and @InverseFalcon already answered/commented. As explained in [resetting query cardinality](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/resetting-query-cardinality/), this issue was caused by executing `CREATE` multiple times.

Queries execute per row. So, when a `MATCH` is followed by a `CREATE`, based on the match results, the CREATE statement might get executed multiple times and create multiple copies of data (unless unique/node key constraints are there) which was originally intended to be created only once.

`MERGE` can help with the issues since it'll not create multiple copies, but the MERGE is still executed multiple times.

This can be handled by *"resetting query cardinality"* using `WITH DISTINCT`. Below shows an updated query that solves the issue, and the figure shows the new results.

```
//Related products
CREATE (rps1:RPS {rpId: 'TGS1108',
  rpName: 'YX Plus Tampered Glass',
  price: 180.99
})
WITH rps1
MATCH (ol1:Outlet {productType: 'New', prId: 'MOB0001'}) //3 match
MATCH (pr1:Product {key: 'MOB0001'})
MERGE (pr1) -[:HAS_RP {typeName: 'Child'}]-> (rps1)
MERGE (rps1) -[:SOLD_THROUGH]-> (ol1)

//next part of query will execute 3 times

//reset cardinality back to 1 with WITH DISTINCT
WITH DISTINCT 1 AS ResetCardinality
CREATE (rps2:RPS {rpId: 'CVR0204',
  rpName: 'YX Plus back cover',
  price: 299.00
}) //now CREATE & following executes only once
WITH rps2
MATCH (ol2:Outlet {productType: 'New', prId: 'MOB0001'})
MATCH (pr2:Product {key: 'MOB0001'})
MERGE (pr2) -[:HAS_RP {typeName: 'ChargeFor'}]-> (rps2)
MERGE (rps2) -[:SOLD_THROUGH]-> (ol2)
```

[image]

Since I'm new to this, if someone can show how the whole situation can be handled better with better written queries, that'll help.